# Social media's in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, twitter, social-media

I have a problem with the social media plugins for my website, The problem is with Twitter and Facebook. Google+ works perfectly.

I'm trying to get the plugins to work with my popup script in jQuery. When they click on a link the popup is added at the end of the body tags. In the function I put the JS code of Facebook, Twitter and Google+, and let the div's place on the right position. Not the problem is When I click on the popup for the first time ( after reload page ) all plugins are working fine. when I close the popup and reopen it. Only Google+ ( or Facebook with the iFrame ) is showing...

everytime when I open the popup this part of the social media plugins I call!

```
                // Google Code
                (function() {
                    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
                    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
                })();
                // Twitter Code
                !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");

                if(options.socialLink != false){
                    var FBsocialLink = 'href='+options.socialLink;
                    var socialLink = 'data-href="'+options.socialLink+'"';
                }
                //show FB
                $('.popup_container').append('<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?'+FBsocialLink+'&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=125&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:125px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>');
                //show Google+
                $('.popup_container').append('<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" '+socialLink+'></div>');
                //show Twitter
                $('.popup_container').append('<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.rednasdesign.nl">Tweet</a>');
```

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're inserting the plugin code each time the popup opens, be sure to call `jQuery("#MyDiv").dialog("destroy");`. See http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ for more information.

Also you may need to set the `parsetags` to `explicit` per https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/ and call `gapi.plusone.render()` in the open event of the jQuery dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the javascript code for the asynchronous loading. It may create a script tag outside the popup window. On the second invocation, it checks that this tag already exists and does nothing. Look for the `if(!d.getElementById(id))` part.

In your case, however, the asynchronous loader does not make sense anyway, as the page is already completely loaded at the time the user opens the popup.

Therefore you can include the external scripts directly. When the popup is shown again, the complete content will be cleared, including those script tags.

```
var socialLink = e.attr("data-link");
var message = e.attr("data-title");
var hashtag = e.attr("data-hashtag");

var html = ''
    + '<div class="socialbutton"><iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href='+socialLink+'&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=125&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:125px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true">Loading Facebook</iframe></div>'
    + '<div class="socialbutton"><div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-href="'+socialLink+'">Loading Google+</div></div>'
    + '<div class="socialbutton"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="' + socialLink + '" data-text="' + message + '" data-hashtags="' + hashtag + '">Loading Twitter</a></div>'

    + '<div><a href="https://stendhalgame.org/wiki/Two_clicks_for_more_privacy" target="_blank">Two clicks for more privacy.</a></div>'

    + '<script async type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>'
    + '<script async type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" id="twitter-wjs"></script>';

$('#popupContent').html(html);
```

There is a little delay between opening the popup windows and the buttons being completely loaded, especially on slow Internet connections. In order to prevent the faster buttons from jumping around, I put them into div.elements for with I defined fixed height of 24px in CSS.